# Read Text File with blank lines

Tags: c, file, scanf

The Text File was writable with 1 blank line after the struct.
Is similar to:

```
1  111 1 Peter

22 22  2 John Lays

3  3   3 Anne Belgs
```

The struct is:

```
struct estruturaCarro {
    int id, potencia, avariado;
    char name[11]; 
} carro;
```

I have write the data to the text File:

```
fprintf(fp, "%-2d %-3d %-1d %-10s \n\n", carro.id, carro.potencia, carro.avariado, carro.name);
```

I read the file data this way, but I'm sure it's not the best way:

```
while(true){
    int result = fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d %10[^\n]", &carro.id, &carro.potencia, &carro.avariado, &carro.name);
    if(result==4){    
            printf("%-2d %-3d %-1d % -s\n", carro.id, carro.potencia, carro.avariado, carro.name);
    }else break;
}
```

How can I read the text file, saving the data struct, without reading the blank lines?
If I want to **validate the values** ​​read (ID = xx, potencia = xxx, avariado = x, name = 10 characters), is it better, before or after filling the array of struct?
The format of each line of the file is:
xx xxx x aaaaaaaaaa (x = digits, a = characters)
For example, if one of the lines is 
`9 123 4 Error 1st value` 
stop reading the file (informing the user), because the line should be:
`9  123 4 Error 1st value` (one space was missing after 9) - or because NAME has more than 10 characters.

Comment: `while( fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d %10[^\n]", &carro.id, &carro.potencia, &carro.avariado, carro.name) == 4) {
                    printf("%-2d %-3d %-1d %-s\n", carro.id, carro.potencia, carro.avariado, carro.name);
        }` seems to work

Comment: Or better, simply use `fgets()` and then `sscanf` to parse. You can check whether the first character in the line is the `'\n'` and simply `continue` to read the next line at that point.

Comment: 10 characters is pretty short for a name. Even my name here on SO is longer than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show how `true` is set in `while(true)`, but it must be based on the return of `fscanf` in the way you are approaching it. You must test three cases:

1. `fscanf` return is `EOF`, read done, `true` should be set to `FALSE` to break loop;
2. `fscanf` return less than `4`, *matching* or *input* failure, no guarantee this occurred due to an empty line; and
3. `fscanf` return is equal to `4`, good input.

Unless you are checking all three, you cannot cover all cases for `fscanf` and further, if there is any additional or extraneous character in your input file, your formatted read will fail.

That is why a better option is to read each line into a buffer with `fgets` and then parse the information you need from the buffer itself with `sscanf`. This provides the benefit of allowing separate validation of (1) the read; and (2) the parse of information. Further, since you are consuming a line-at-a-time, there is no uncertainty on what remains in the input stream and a failure in parsing any one line does not prevent a successful read of the remainder.

A short implementation with `fgets()` and `sscanf()` reading each struct into an array-of-struct, you can do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXN   11   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXC 1024   /*         (don't skimp on buffer size)          */

typedef struct {    /* use a simple typedef */
    int id, potencia, avariado;
    char name[MAXN]; 
} carro_t;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC];                         /* buffer to read line */
    carro_t carro[MAXN] = {{ .id = 0 }};    /* array of struct  */
    size_t ndx = 0;                         /* array index      */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (ndx < MAXN && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {   /* read each line */
        carro_t tmp = { .id = 0 };                  /* temp struct */
        if (*buf == '\n')           /* if line empty */
            continue;               /* get next line */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d %d %d %10[^\n]",   /* separate/validate */
                    &tmp.id, &tmp.potencia, &tmp.avariado, tmp.name) == 4)
            carro[ndx++] = tmp;     /* add to array of struct */
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ndx; i++)
        printf ("%3d  %3d  %3d  %s\n",
            carro[i].id, carro[i].potencia, carro[i].avariado, carro[i].name);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** the filename is provide as the first argument to the program, or if no filename is provided, read from `stdin` by default)

While with your particular data file, there is no reason you cannot use `fscanf`, it is fragile and one character too many (like `"Anne Belgss"`) will cause it to break. A `fscanf` implementation removing the `true` and simply looping as you have could be:

```
    for (;;) {
        carro_t tmp = { .id = 0 };
        if (fscanf (fp, "%d %d %d %10[^\n]",    /* separate/validate */
                    &tmp.id, &tmp.potencia, &tmp.avariado, tmp.name) == 4)
            carro[ndx++] = tmp;     /* add to array of struct */
        else
            break;
    }
```

Either way, you will produce the same output with "this" input file, e.g.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/readwblanks ~/tmpd/file
  1  111    1  Peter
 22   22    2  John Lays
  3    3    3  Anne Belgs
```

Comment: David, can you suggest me a resolution to the last added doubt? Thanks.

Comment: If I understand and you want to match the lines against a test line, you can actually do it one of two ways. Normally, you will read all data from the file and then you can query the data however you like. The second instance is where you only want to read one value from the file. If you are guaranteed that the whitespace in your search `"xx xxx x aaaaaaaaaa"` exactly matches the whitespace in the file, you can just use a simply `strcmp` on each line read. Normally though, that isn't guaranteed. So reading the struct and comparing members is best. File I/O is slow. So read all into struct.

Answer (score 0):

just use simple reading way is ok,like this.

```
    while(fscanf(fp,"%d %d %d %s",&carro.id,&carro.potencia,&carro.avariado,carro.name)!=EOF)
    printf("%d %d %d %s\n",carro.id,carro.potencia,carro.avariado,carro.name);
```

result is like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD4ZQ.png)

Comment: Will fail with `"%s"` used to read the 'name' field as `"%s"` reads up to the first *whitespace* is encountered leaving the second part of the name unread leading to a *matching failure* on the next call to `fscanf`.